# При захвате кадра с web-камеры выскакивает лишнее окно "выбор источника видео"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, web-камера

Уже в который раз сталкиваюсь с какими-то непонятным глюком, не глюком.
На некоторых ПК почему-то выскакивает окно "выбор источника видео" (см. скрин), при захвате видео моим ПО (фото идёт в БД). К камере подключаюсь через AVICAP32.DLL, для захвата и через directshow9, для масштабирования.
Это было бы и о понятно, там где стояло бы несколько источников видео, но в тех ПК либо ноутбуках камера установлена лишь одна камера, так по крайне мере показывает диспетчер устройств.

Как обойти вызов драйвером данного окна?

P.S. Скрин не мой, в моём случае прописана там уже камера по умолчанию.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

- Вопрос решил переводом всего ПО на directshow9.

Comment: Так переведите с другого языка

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Вы думали попыток не было? Я наверное не такой гуру программирования, но на лету переводить код из одного неизвестного мне языка программирования в другой, не умею. Особенно, когда это касается не часто мне встречающихся областей программирования.

Comment: Тогда, наверное, стоило задать вопрос с просьбой помочь с переводом и выложив те куски кода, которые вызывают затруднение